# Animating margin via jquery

Tags: jquery, css, animation

So, I'm trying to make smooth nav bar animation when page is being resized.
This is how it should look like when page is 1500+px width and less then 1500px.

[this is 1500px+ width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLv2S.png)

[this is less then 1500px width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ll7mR.png)

this is the jquery code I'm using to animate that transition:

```
       $(window).on('resize', function(){
           if($(this).width() <= 1500){
               $('#visas').animate({'margin-left':'0%', 'margin-right':'0%'});
           }
           if($(this).width() >1500){
               $('#visas').animate({'margin-left':'20%', 'margin-right':'20%'});
           } 
        });
```

When I'm resizing page to less then 1500px animation happens sometimes, but when I'm trying to resize page to more then 1500px margin doesn't change.

Comment: You have to throttle it, so it only animates once when the value goes below/above 1500 etc. not on every resize event, which triggers continuously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing it in jQuery use CSS with transitions and media queries:

```
#visas {
  height: 50px;
  background: #bada55;
  margin: 0%;
  transition: margin .5s ease;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  #visas {
    margin: 0 20%;
  }
}
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ukwybf9g/

Comment: Thanks! It work perfect!
Is it a long code to do this with jquery tho?

Answer (score 0):

You need to employ the use of media queries. Like this:

```
@media (max-width:1500px){
   .nav{
      width: 100%;
      margin:0 auto;
   }
}
```

In my demo I used 1200px as my breaking point to test it because my laptop doesn't go to far out past the 1500px, but you'll get the idea. Just change the 1200px breakpoint to 1500px.

p.s. Get familiar with Bootstrap. You can do these things much easier with the help of a responsive framework

See Demo [**HERE**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obxOEB)

Comment: You forgot something: `smooth nav bar animation` ;)

Comment: I'm not into doing everything with templates. I like to create my own things from zero. I'm that kind of guy that likes to write code. Ofc, it saves time and later on I will have to switch to bootsrap, I guess. :)

Comment: Bootstrap is not a template my friend lol. Do you use JQuery or do you write every script from scratch? Is the same thing. Bootstrap is a front end framework. In fact, in the professional world, (in most cases) you'd be asked if you are familiar with Bootstrap to be eligible for the job. I get you want to do everything from scratch, but some things shouldn't. But good luck!